# cannot convert Key<T> expression to type Key<T>?

Tags: c#, generics

I can't find what's wrong in this code and the error didn't help me much:

```
public class Track<T> {

    readonly List<Key<T>> _keys = new List<Key<T>>();

    public void AddKey<T>(float time, T value) {
        var key = new Key<T> {
            Time = time,
            Value = value
        };
        _keys.Add(key); // <== Error: cannot convert Key<T> expression to type Key<T>
    }
}

public struct Key<T> {
    public float Time;
    public T Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've *redefined* template in the method:

```
// Here's one "T"
public class Track<T> {
    readonly List<Key<T>> _keys = new List<Key<T>>();

    // ... And here is a different "T" which hides original (from Track<T>) one 
    // the declaration equals to 
    // public void AddKey<K>(float time, K value) {
    public void AddKey<T>(float time, T value) {
      // T has been redefined, so "new Key<T>" (with redefined T)
      // is not equal to Key<T> from List<Key<T>> _keys which uses class template T
      ... 
    }
}
```

try *removing* `T` from the method:

```
public class Track<T> {
    ...    
    // No "<T>" declaration here, uses "T" from Track<T>
    public void AddKey(float time, T value) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get this is because you define template class AND also a template method. If you change it to `AddKey<K>` you will understand what Im talking about.
Try to change it like this:

```
public class Track<T> {

    readonly List<Key<T>> _keys = new List<Key<T>>();

    public void AddKey(float time, T value) {
        var key = new Key<T> {
            Time = time,
            Value = value
        };
        _keys.Add(key); // <== Error: cannot convert Key<T> expression to type Key<T>
    }
}

public struct Key<T> {
    public float Time;
    public T Value;
}
```

Comment: Yes that's it! But I don't fully understand the reason. AddKey shouldn't be a template method. But why? I'm probably missing something basic.

Comment: Method also can be templated. So you just misunderstood behavior of templates. If you template class then this template type will be availible everywhere without <T> in methods.

Answer (score 0):

The `T` type in your `AddKey` method is not the same type as the generic type argument `T` of your `Track<T>` class.

So the variable `key`'s type is the `Key<T>` where `T` is defined in the scope of the method. However, `_keys.Add` needs an argument of type `Key<T>` where `T` is defined in the class declaration. That's why the error appears.

To fix this, simply remove the `T` from the method so it looks like this:

```
public void AddKey(float time, T value) {
```

Now the `T` in `T value` refers to the class's generic type argument because there is no other `T` that it can refer to!